# JS Socket not passing special characters correctly

Tags: javascript, html, flask, encoding

So, I've seen this question around a lot but the accepted answer isn't working for me. I have this chatroom-like site I'm working on, and while it works fine for most of it (I'm aware of a few other minor issues with my code but they're not part of the question), I'm having issues with the character encoding whenever my JS file is involved and I use sockets. I'll post my HTML and JS files now:

**HTML:**

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block heading %}
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/chatroom.js') }}"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/chatroom.css') }}">
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
    The Chatroom name is <span id="chatroom">{{ chatroom }}</span> and it's code is <span id="code">{{ code }}</span>
    <div id="messages">
    {% for message in messages %}
        {% if message.author == online_user %}
            <div class="own">{{ message.message }}</div>
        {% else %}
            <div class="other"><strong>{{ message.author }}</strong><br> {{ message.message }}</div>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <textarea id="message" rows=5 cols=50></textarea>
    <input type="button" id="send" value="Send">
{% endblock %}
```

**JS:**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
    socket.on('connect', () => {
        document.querySelector('#send').onclick = () => {
            const message = document.querySelector('#message').value;
            socket.emit('send message', {'chatroom': {'code':document.querySelector('#code').innerHTML, 'name': document.querySelector('#chatroom').innerHTML}, 'message': message});
        };
    });
    socket.on('broadcast message', data => {
        if (data.message['chatroom']['code'] == document.querySelector('#code').innerHTML) {
            const msg = document.createElement('div');
            if (data.message['author'] == document.getElementById('current_user').innerHTML)
                msg.innerHTML = data.message['message'];
            else
                msg.innerHTML = `${data.message['author']}: ${data.message['message']}`
            document.querySelector('#messages').append(msg);
            var listlen = document.getElementById('messages').getElementsByTagName('div').length;
            while (listlen > 100) {
                var msglist = document.getElementById('messages');
                msglist.removeChild(msglist.childNodes[0]);
                var listlen = document.getElementById('messages').getElementsByTagName('div').length;
            };
        };
    });
});
```

Now, when the JS file and socketing isn't involved (for example, if I log into the site) the encoding works fine. However, when the textarea holds special characters such as Á (I'll use the word Ángel on both fields as an example), once I hit the send button (not before), the output is wrong.

Current output: `{'chatroom': {'code': 'ouAY7mxCvhXb', 'name': 'UTF'}, 'author': 'Ángel', 'message': 'Ã\x81ngel'}`

Expected output: `{'chatroom': {'code': 'ouAY7mxCvhXb', 'name': 'UTF'}, 'author': 'Ángel', 'message': 'Ángel'}`

The accepted answer for other questions marking this issue was adding the `<meta charset="UTF-8">` line on my HTML, but I'm puzzled now since it hasn't worked. I also checked and my JS file is properly encoded to UTF-8 as well.

**EDIT:**

I'll add the server side code for the socket since it might as well help understand the output better. As seen here, the problem with the encoding only happens from what I pass from `data` (which can go wrong only on the message's content and chatroom's name, because the chatroom code is automatically generated and never includes special characters).

```
@socketio.on("send message")
def send_message(data):
    data['message'] = data['message'].strip()
    if len(data["message"]) > 0:
        message = {'chatroom': data['chatroom'], 'author': session['username'], 'message': data['message']}
        print(message)
        stored_messages.append(message)
        local_messages.append(message)
        emit("broadcast message", {'message': message}, broadcast=True)
```

Comment: It's only a guess, but does your `layout.html` defines both `head` and `heading` blocks? if so, your child layout should put the `meta` tag under the `head` block (or just go ahead and put the `meta` tag in `layout.html`). Let me know if that helps and I'll post that as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The ```heading``` block is a part of the ```head``` on my layout. I tried moving the ```meta``` to the layout but the problem persists. I'll add the server side code to the original post as well to see if something's wrong over there.

Comment: Just to make sure: when your page renders, is `<meta charset="UTF-8">` nested under `<head>`?

Comment: Yes, it's the first line inside the head tag right now, both in the file and when rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future references if someone runs into this problem, I found out a way to deal with it. Instead of passing the raw message through the socket and expecting the program to automatically transform it to UTF-8 with the meta tag, I encoded it by adding an encoding function on the JS file and applying it to the message content.

```
    function encode_utf8(s) {
        return encodeURIComponent(s);
    }
```

Former line 4 of JS file now looks like this: `const message = encode_utf8(document.querySelector('#message').value);`

That allows me send it encoded in a way my backend server can properly decode so it returns the expected output by using the `urllib.parse` library's `unquote_plus`.

```
@socketio.on("send message")
def send_message(data):
    data['message'] = data['message'].strip()
    print(data)
    if len(data["message"]) > 0:
        message = {'chatroom': data['chatroom'], 'author': session['username'], 'message': urllib.parse.unquote_plus(data['message'])} # <-- Modified line
        print(message)
        stored_messages.append(message)
        local_messages.append(message)
        emit("broadcast message", {'message': message}, broadcast=True)
```